# how to use cookiecutter-django scss

Tags: node.js, django, sass, compass, cookiecutter-django

I used the recent cookiecutter django package to generate a new django product.  But I am having trouble with the sass/scss compilation aspect.

I looked at [this](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/live-reloading-and-sass-compilation.html), and its no help, as I need to setup the package.json to run any commands.

I tried to make one, but I cannot seem to get it to run.

```
{
  "name": "my_awesome_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Awesome Project ==================",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "docs"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "scss": "sass --load-path my_awesome_project/static/sass/ my_awesome_project/static/css/a.css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "compass": "^0.1.1"
  }
}
```

In all honesty,  I don't really know what Im doing with this part, nor where to start.

Comment: What cookiecutter options have you selected? I would recommend trying out the Gulp task runner + Custom bootstrap compilation, I'm under the impression that the page of the docs you link to is out of date...

Comment: To get a similar project you can just use the default responses for all the cookie cutter questions. I have not tried the gulp runner. I’m mostly worked with backend stuff so the front end is elusive for me.